# JACK Audio Connection Kit with Surround Sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 LTS (64 bit version).

Also, I always use JACK Audio Connection Kit 1.9.20.

Also, I use JAMin, as a real time audio dynamic processor (to get the best high level against the environment noise).

Please, it is not a question. It is a guide to get full control of all the 8 audio channels present in the today audio cards.

1. Open a Terminal session.
2. Type:

   If you have installed "gedit":

   ```
    sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

    (The system will prompt your root password)
   ```

   If you have installed "mousepad":

   ```
    sudo mousepad /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

    (The system will prompt your root password)
   ```
3. Look for the line which has the following sentence:

   ```
    ; default-sample-channels = 2
   ```
4. Change the line value from 2 to 8 (if you have a 7.1 surround audio system):

   ```
    default-sample-channels = 8
   ```
5. Look for the line which has the following sentence:

   ```
   ; enable-lfe-remixing = no
   ```
6. Change the line value from no to yes and eliminate semicolon:

   ```
   enable-lfe-remixing = yes
   ```
7. If you are using jackd (Jack Audio Connections Kit), you also have to edit the file:

   ```
   /etc/pulse/default.pa
   ```
8. Look for the lines above the title:

   ```
   "Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present"
   ```
9. Add the following lines:

   ```
   load-module module-jack-sink

   load-module module-jack-source

   load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=8
   ```
10. Restart your computer, or type:

    ```
    killall pulseaudio && pulseaudio
    ```
11. Now,check your PulseAudio sound system with:

    ```
    speaker-test -c8 -l1 -twhite
    ```

Then, you will get the following audio connections diagram (QjackCtl app):

[image]

In this way, you will be able to control all your audio cards channels.

That's all, folks!!!